# Can't get values from input via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm simply trying to take inputs from html `input` fields. 
The problem is, my function always evaluate the inputs to 0. 
What should I do my code to work as I expected (to take inputs from fields and pass them to my javascript functions). If there is alike answered questions asked before, please refer.

Please do not propose jQuery solutions - I can't follow its full of parantheses syntax.

P.S. Zeros on ternary, are just for avoiding NaNs. Nothing else.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <strong>Data</strong>
  <hr>Price:
  <input type="text" id="price" value="0">
  <br>Prepay:
  <input type="text" id="prepay" value="0">
  <br>Percent:
  <input type="text" id="percent" value="0">
  <br>Month:
  <input type="text" id="month" value="0" onchange="refactorTable('payment-plan')">
  <br>

  <hr>
  <strong>Table</strong>

  <table id="payment-plan" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Month</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    var PrePayment = parseInt(document.getElementById('prepay').value);
    var Percent = parseInt(document.getElementById('percent').value);
    var Month = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);

     //console.log(Sum +" -- "+ PrePayment +" -- "+ Percent +" -- "+ Month);

    function monthlyPaymentPlan(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) {

      var BigJohn = Sum - PrePayment;
      //console.log(BigJohn);
      var monthly = Math.ceil((BigJohn + BigJohn * Percent) / Month);
      return Month > 0 ? monthly : 0;

    }

    function lastMonth(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) {
      return Month > 0 ? Sum - monthlyPaymentPlan(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) * (Month - 1) : 0;
    }

    function refactorTable(tbl_id) {
      var table = document.getElementById(tbl_id).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
      table.innerHTML = "";
      var i = 0;
      var rows = document.getElementById('month').value;
      rows = parseInt(rows);
      for (i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
        table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td>" + monthlyPaymentPlan(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) + "</td>";
      }
      table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = "<td>" + rows + "</td><td>" + lastMonth(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) + "</td>";
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are reading the values before the user had a chance to change them. You need to get them when you need them, i.e. When `refactorTable` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Sum        = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
```

This is not defining a function, or a macro. This is a one-time calculation of a number, and it seems this is going to happen when the page starts up. So, it won't ever change from its first value (0).

You should probably move these declarations inside of `refactorTable`. Thankfully, you already have them set up to be passed as arguments.

Comment: is this only way to make these variables reactive?

Comment: No, but ultimately, getting the correct value each time you reference it is going to mean running most of the above line. If you like, you could retrieve `document.getElementById('price')` and store it as `SumElement` or `SumNode`; this will be an actual *reference* that constantly reflects the actual input element. You can retrieve `value` from that, and it should be correct each time.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the values when the page renders, instead of when the function is supposed to run.  Place your assignments inside a function and call the function.

```
// Define the variables globally so they can be used in any function
var Sum;
var PrePayment;
var Percent;
var Month;

// Call this function to set the values of the global variables.
function getValues() {
    Sum        = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    PrePayment = parseInt(document.getElementById('prepay').value);
    Percent    = parseInt(document.getElementById('percent').value);
    Month      = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);
}

// Call the getValues function first to set the values and then continue on 
// with your function calculations.
function refactorTable(tbl_id) {
   getValues();
   // Do the rest...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the values at the time the function is called. Right now you're getting the values on page load (which is 0).

```
function refactorTable(tbl_id) {
    var Sum        = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    var PrePayment = parseInt(document.getElementById('prepay').value);
    var Percent    = parseInt(document.getElementById('percent').value);
    var Month      = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);

    var table = document.getElementById(tbl_id).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    table.innerHTML = "";
    var i=0;
    var rows = document.getElementById('month').value;
    rows = parseInt(rows);
    for(i=0; i<rows-1; i++) {
        table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = "<td>" + (i+1) + "</td><td>" + monthlyPaymentPlan(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) + "</td>";
    } 
    table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = "<td>" + rows + "</td><td>" + lastMonth(Sum, PrePayment, Percent, Month) + "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have need to update input variable value on change of id="month" so you can get updated value.

```
var Sum = '';
var PrePayment = '';
var Percent = '';
var Month = '';
function inputsval() {
   Sum = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
   PrePayment = parseInt(document.getElementById('prepay').value);
   Percent = parseInt(document.getElementById('percent').value);
   Month = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);
}
function refactorTable(tbl_id) {
   inputsval();
   //Your other code.....
}
```